# how do i scrape class with specific name

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all classes with name

```
all_posts = soup.findAll(class_='s-result-item celwidget')
```

but the problem is it come out as null.

And if i remove celwidget and try this

```
all_posts = soup.findAll(class_='s-result-item')
```

it comes with a result but then it includes both classes

```
s-result-item celwidget

s-result-item aok-hidden
```

i only need `s-result-item celwidget` data

please someone help

Comment: You need to provide a sample html file or at least a relevant subset of it that is still valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using re module you can find.

```
import re
all_posts = soup.findAll(class_=re.compile("celwidget"))
```

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
data='''<html>
<div class="s-result-item celwidget">Text1</div>
<div class="s-result-item aok-hidden">Text2</div>
</html>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
all_posts = soup.findAll(class_=re.compile('celwidget'))
for post in all_posts:
  print(post.text)
```

**Option 2**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<html>
<div class="s-result-item celwidget">Text1</div>
<div class="s-result-item aok-hidden">Text2</div>
</html>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
all_posts = soup.find_all(class_="s-result-item")
print(all_posts[0].text)
```

**option 3:** Use select_one

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<html>
<div class="s-result-item celwidget">Text1</div>
<div class="s-result-item aok-hidden">Text2</div>
</html>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
all_posts = soup.select_one('.s-result-item.celwidget')
print(all_posts.text)
```

Comment: this does not work,  class name is s-result-item so how it is going to find it

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal : you have mentioned in your post you have two class such as `s-result-item celwidget` and 

`s-result-item aok-hidden` right. And you want  to get `s-result-item celwidget` this class right.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal : see the second answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to match multiple cases of that compound class. If using css selectors you need to use `select`, not `select_one`, as `select_one` will only return first match

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")
all_posts = soup.select('.s-result-item.celwidget')
```

Note that compound classes are joined by "."

Comment: Did you try this? It should be faster